# How to delete all workspaces in TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

How do I delete all workspaces on the automated build server?  We had an issue where we had to keep changing the credentials on the build agent for TFS 2010, and then if we tried to deploy the build next time for all our build definitions it gave the error that the workspace already existed under a different user.

I know we can do this:

```
tf workspace /delete /server:http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection 26_1_internalserver123;MYOFFICE\brian.colley
```

But we have to manually do that for every build definition, and we don't really know the workspace number until we try and run the build and it gives the error.

In MSDN it says you can do a /remove:*, but /delete:* doesn't work (or isn't even in the msdn command options which is weird).  I didn't know if remove is doing something that I don't want, versus delete.

Should I do this, or will it mess up all the users in TFS on their local boxes?

```
c:\projects>tf workspaces /remove:* /collection:http://myserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Install [TFS Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/), you can clean them up with a nice pretty GUI.

you can filter by the build account and a machine and then delete only the specific workspaces you are interested in

Comment: Yah, I had tried to install that before and couldn't get it working about a month ago.. crashed on me.  I was hoping for a way to just do it in the console with a wildcard.